# The distinct() command in sf?

Tags: r, r-sf

Does `sf::` have a function similar to `distinct()` but with the opposite objective to identify all points, lines, polygons etc... that have the same geometry?  I saw something in `sp::` called `zerodist()`, but couldn't seem to get `distinct()` to function in an opposite manner, somewhat analogous to `unique()` and `duplicated()`.  Thanks!

```
some_pt <- st_sfc(st_point(1:2)) %>%
  st_sf()
also_some_pt <- st_sfc(st_point(1:2)) %>%
  st_sf()
some_diff_pt <- st_sfc(st_point(2:1)) %>%
  st_sf()
  
three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place <- rbind(some_pt,also_some_pt,some_diff_pt)

distinct(three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place)
```

Comment: Solicitation of recommendations are at the border of what's acceptable. You should post code that creates a data structure for testing and demonstration and say very specifically what results are expected.

Comment: Like `sf::st_equals`? Or `sf::st_distance`, testing for 0 distance? Beyond reading through the package docs, it's unclear what you're asking exactly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your needs.

If you want perfect matching you can use `sf::st_equal` or `sf::st_equal_exact` (I never used the last one).

You can also use:

`sf::st_relate(three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place,  pattern = "T*F**FFF*",  sparse = FALSE)`

This will return you a matrix of intersection between your 3 points (3 x 3 matrix). If you add more points this matrix will grow.

|  | some_pt | also_some_pt | some_diff_pt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some_pt | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| also_some_pt | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| some_diff_pt | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |

If you change the `sparse` argument:

`sf::st_relate(three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place,  pattern = "T*F**FFF*",  sparse = TRUE)`

This will return you a list for each geometry with the index of geometries matching the pattern:

> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 3, where the predicate
> was `relate_pattern'  1: 1, 2  2: 1, 2  3: 3

Example: `1:1,2` means that `some_pt` is related (here "equals") with himself and `also_some_pt`.

Then you can just use `lengths` (see length**S**) and keep only `result == 1`.

```
my_result <- sf::st_relate(three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place,  pattern = "T*F**FFF*",  sparse = TRUE)

three_pts_w2_in_the_same_place[lengths(my_result) == 1,]
```

I find the Wikipedia link useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM and you can also find examples more R related [here](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#de-9im-strings) and the use of lengths a bit [after](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-operations.html#spatial-subsetting).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sf::` has a `distinct.sf()` tidyverse method that selects unique/distinct rows/geometries. For example:

```
library(sf)
library(tmaptools)

locs <- tmaptools::geocode_OSM(c("Cuba, Portugal",
                                 "Cuba, Portugal",
                                 "Havana, Cuba"),
                               as.sf = TRUE)

locs # sf object with repeated geometries:
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 7 fields
# Active geometry column: point
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -82.35896 ymin: 23.1353 xmax: -7.89253 ymax: 38.16521
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# query      lat       lon  lat_min  lat_max    lon_min    lon_max
# 1 Cuba, Portugal 38.16521  -7.89253 38.10583 38.30527  -8.003305  -7.837004
# 2 Cuba, Portugal 38.16521  -7.89253 38.10583 38.30527  -8.003305  -7.837004
# 3   Havana, Cuba 23.13530 -82.35896 22.93371 23.38577 -82.607263 -82.081421
# bbox                     point
# 1 POLYGON ((-8.003305 38.1058... POINT (-7.89253 38.16521)
#             2 POLYGON ((-8.003305 38.1058... POINT (-7.89253 38.16521)
#                         3 POLYGON ((-82.60726 22.9337... POINT (-82.35896 23.1353)

locs %>% dplyr::distinct() # Unique/distinct rows/geometries (of the active geometry type POINT) are selected: 
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 7 fields
# Active geometry column: point
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -82.35896 ymin: 23.1353 xmax: -7.89253 ymax: 38.16521
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# query      lat       lon  lat_min  lat_max    lon_min    lon_max
# 1 Cuba, Portugal 38.16521  -7.89253 38.10583 38.30527  -8.003305  -7.837004
# 2   Havana, Cuba 23.13530 -82.35896 22.93371 23.38577 -82.607263 -82.081421
# bbox                     point
# 1 POLYGON ((-8.003305 38.1058... POINT (-7.89253 38.16521)
#             2 POLYGON ((-82.60726 22.9337... POINT (-82.35896 23.1353)
```